# How to compare and count instances of several objects' property values placed in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I've been trying to count property value instances of several objects placed in array.I am on the stage of finding a way to effectively iterate over these values.
The structure of array may look as follows:

```
var arr=[{1:["option1","option2"],2:["option2"],3:["option1"]},{1:["option2","option1"],2:["option1"],3:["option1"]}]
```

Array may contain unknown number of objects. Each object property may contain unknown number of values put into array. Each object has same properties, so I simply tried to merge all objects properties with the first object. As I believe, it looks clumsy and poorly readable, but it's the only way I found so far. It almost works, but I believe the behaviour may be unpredictable.

```
for(var firstobj=0,val=0,i=1,prop=1;arr.length>i;prop++,val++)
{
 if(prop>Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arr[i]).length)
{
    i++;
    prop=1;
}
else if(prop<Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arr[i]).length)
{
    i+0;
}
if(arr[i][prop].length<=val)
 {
  val=0;  
}
arr[firstobj][prop].push(arr[i][prop][val]);
}
```

As you see, I try to manipulate iteration by moving to next array index (i) only when object's properties [prop] reach the end and try to control internal array iteration by defaulting val to 0, if it grows larger than array's length. However, I am not satisfied with this code. May be you can suggest any other solutions to the problem. How can I better prepare multiple object values in order to later count their occurences for each property? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't nested loops be easier than your way of resetting the index?

Comment: Hm,as a novice to js, I did not think about this approach. Can you provide me with some illustration based on my example?

Comment: It's not JS-specific, it's how you process multi-dimensional or nested data structures in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested loops to process each level of array or object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj = arr[i];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // skip properties inherited from prototype
            var arr2 = obj[key];
            for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
                // Do something with arr2[j]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped!) It's much more easier and comprehensible