# How to count value occurences in several objects in js array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects that have same properties and different property values.

```
var arr = [{
    1: ["option1", "option2"],
    2: ["option2"],
    3: ["option1"]
}, {
    1: ["option2", "option1"],
    2: ["option1"],
    3: ["option1"]
}];
```

I want to count value occurences for **each property (which are the same in all objects)**, so I need to merge those objects somehow or may be do comparison in the other way.

Guys here helped me to iterate over it by using nested loops [How to compare and count instances of several objects' property values placed in array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302480/how-to-compare-and-count-instances-of-several-objects-property-values-placed-in/23302583#23302583)

However, I am not sure it resolves the problem. With the code below I cannot still figure out how to merge property values of each object into one object so that properties match. Please help.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj = arr[i];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // skip properties inherited from prototype
            var arr2 = obj[key];
            for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
                // Do something with arr2[j]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The resultant structure is

```
{
    1: {
        option1: 2,
        option2: 2
    },
    2: {
        option2: 1,
        option1: 1
    },
    3: {
        option1: 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Note you should use arrays instead of objects with keys `1`,`2`,`3`

Comment: I get data from JSON, so it is stored in objects. Can you explain why shouldn't I use numeric keys for objects. As far as I know, this is not prohibited in JS?

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to use objects if you want (and arrays are objects anyway). But arrays were made to simplify working with objects whose keys are natural numbers, which is the case.

Comment: This question is worded horribly. At least provide an example of the response you expect. So far two of us have been shooting blindly at what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Version 1

```
var count = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj = arr[i];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var arr2 = obj[key];
            for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
                count[arr2[j]] = (count[arr2[j]] || 0) + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
{
    option1: 5,
    option2: 3
}
```

## Version 2

```
var count = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj = arr[i];
    count[i] = {};
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var arr2 = obj[key];
            for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
                count[i][arr2[j]] = (count[i][arr2[j]] || 0) + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
[
    {
        option1: 2,
        option2: 2
    },{
        option2: 1,
        option1: 3
    }
]
```

## Version 3

```
var count = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj = arr[i];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if(!count[key]) count[key] = {};
            var arr2 = obj[key];
            for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
                count[key][arr2[j]] = (count[key][arr2[j]] || 0) + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
{
    1: {
        option1: 2,
        option2: 2
    },
    2: {
        option2: 1,
        option1: 1
    },
    3: {
        option1: 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this counts general value occurences. I need to know how often a given value occurs for each of the objects' property. These properties are the same in all objects

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. firebug says that count[i] is undefined. and no log for count in console.log

Comment: @user25815 It works for me in console. `count[i]` shouldn't be undefined because of `count[i] = {}`

Comment: Version3 is just what I need. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do this, using underscore and at the expense of some efficiency, trying to make it a little more readable (it's always hard to follow loops that nest 3 levels deep):

(underscore docs are available at http://underscorejs.org/)

```
var arr = [{
    1: ["option1", "option2"],
    2: ["option2"],
    3: ["option1"]
}, {
    1: ["option2", "option1"],
    2: ["option1"],
    3: ["option1"]
}];
var counts = {};
var flattened = _.map(arr, function(item, index) {
    index++;
    counts[index] = {};
    var values = _.flatten(_.values(item));
    _.each(values, function(val) {
        counts[index][val] = (counts[val] || 0) + 1;
    });
    return counts;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(counts));
// prints: [{"1":{"option1":1,"option2":1},"2":{"option2":1,"option1":1}},{"1":{"option1":1,"option2":1},"2":{"option2":1,"option1":1}}]
```

The relevant jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8yx6P/3/

Comment: Thanks,but still I need to know not overall count of options1, options2 etc., but the ccount for each property (1,2,3). I need to know how many option1, option2 etc. are for property "1","2" or "3" separately.

Comment: I see an empty textarea in your jsfiddle. Nothing logs. Anyway thanks for your answer, Sorry I can't accept two answers

Comment: `console.log` will print to the javascript console. google `chrome javascript console` to find out how to show it. If you provide an example of the object you want to see generated, I can tailer my code to generate it.  For example, do you want this?
`[{2:"option1",2:"option2"},{1:"option2",3:"option1"}]`

Comment: I needed structure like this {
    1: {
        option1: 2,
        option2: 2
    },
    2: {
        option2: 1,
        option1: 1
    },
    3: {
        option1: 2
    }
} Anyway,thanks! Please tell me how can I upvote your help. May be there are options other than accepting the answer. I cannot upvote your answer,because short of reputation)

Comment: I've updated my code, and the jsfiddle. You should see the data in the text area.